# Передвижение области графика MSChart мышью

Tags: c#, диаграммы

Есть MSChart, в сети нашел как сделать так, что бы область вывода графика увеличивалась с добавлением данных, нашел пример как показать полосы прокрутки на осях, что бы можно было прокручивать график. Сейчас необходимо сделать передвижение графика мышкой, т.е. зажать на области вывода графика кнопку мыши и таскать её в разные стороны и что бы сам график при этом тоже передвигался. Никак не могу сообразить, что нужно для этого сделать, контрол очень сложный.

Comment: WinForms полагаю? Тогда вам сюда https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartarea.position(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем спасибо за участие, получилось вот так, работает:

```
    private bool isLeftButtonPressed = false;
    private Point mouseDown = Point.Empty;

    private void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isLeftButtonPressed)
        {
            var result = chart1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

            if (result.ChartElementType == System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartElementType.PlottingArea)
            {
                var oldXValue = result.ChartArea.AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(mouseDown.X);
                var newXValue = result.ChartArea.AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.X);

                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Position += oldXValue - newXValue;
                mouseDown.X = e.X;
            }
        }
    }

    private void chart1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            isLeftButtonPressed = false;
            mouseDown = Point.Empty;
        }
    }

    private void chart1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            isLeftButtonPressed = true;
            mouseDown = e.Location;

        }
    }
```